# Using border-image properly

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement the border-image property in a div I have created, I would like the leaf image (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/leafy.png/) to go around the edge of the div.

I have attempted to do it but cannot get the leaves to look normal and they seem to overlap in the corners, I find the border-image property really confusing and frustrating, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

The code that I am using is here: jsfiddle.net/MQrd6/

And what I am trying to achieve (roughly) is here: http://imageshack.us/a/img203/1029/concepto.png

Also I know IE (as usual) doesn't support the border-image property, is there a workaround to this? Using javascript or something?

Really appreciate any help :)

Comment: For what I see in your links yo did not started yet :)   For a full-cross-browser solution, you could use a "fake-border". Its a simple and clean tech. In order to implement it you will be required to know about: positioning, z-index and some experience in lay out.

Comment: Do you have any links on how I would go about doing that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MQrd6/3/

The trick is to set the width of `border-image` same as `border-width`:

```
#leaf {
    width: 760px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-width: 22px;
    border-image: url(http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/4976/leafy.png) 22 22 round;
}
```

No versions of IE supports border-image. To give support in IE you could try [CSS3pie](http://css3pie.com/), a simple library that allows you to use several CSS3 features in IE6 or higher.

Comment: It worked! Thanks alot really helped and cleared things up! Now to attempt the dreaded IE conversion :P

Thanks Again!

Comment: Glad to help you! ;) If you experience any problem with CSS3Pie, this site has a lot of questions related. Luck!

Comment: Just tried CSS3Pie both v1.0 and 2.0beta and in both instances the border-image doesnt show up :/

Comment: Here I paste you a link with a lot of test-cases of the css3 features supported with CSS3Pie: http://www.flashjunior.ch/school/test/ietest/pie/ It seems there's a bug with border-image http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=75 But continue searching, because the moderator will paddle us if we continue this conversation in this post xD  If you continue experimenting issues post it as new question, please ;)

Answer (score 0):

there is css instruction for image border:

**CSS**

```
-moz-border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
-webkit-border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
```

More information on:

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

AND

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Comment: I already consulted both of those and as you can see in my example code it didn't work out, I was hoping someone would be able to point out where I went wrong not just post a standard response but thanks anyway!